# Seeking compressive sensing imaging demo in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, compressive-sensing, soft-question

I am looking to experiment in MATLAB with image restoration/reconstruction using compressed sensing. I am relatively new to compressive sensing, and was inspired by the following Wired article to learn more about it:

- [Fill in the Blanks: Using Math to Turn Lo-Res Datasets Into Hi-Res Samples](http://www.wired.com/2010/02/ff_algorithm/)

In the Wired article linked above, the authors show a low-res picture of US President Obama, and snapshots of the image as it progresses through various stages of "recovery," ultimately ending up with a clean-looking image.

I have read quite a few papers, and even have coded a simple algorithm for sparse signal recovery in MATLAB, but I would like to be able to "play around" with a low-quality image in MATLAB, using some compressed sensing algorithms. I think it would help solidify my understanding of what is going on by incorporating a visual example.

So does anyone know of any such MATLAB demos/examples which provide the MATLAB code and a sample image (or images) that would permit one to experiment with the recovery process?

Comment: Do you need additional details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with the [Compressive Imaging Code](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~justin/spmag/) code by J. Romberg, illustrating the paper  "[Imaging via Compressive Sampling](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~justin/spmag/assets/csup-short.pdf)".

Another great source of information and codes is on [Nuit Blanche](http://nuit-blanche.blogspot.fr/p/blog-page_4.html).

Answer (score 2):

The following links have papers and usually have the associated code:

- [l1 magic](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/l1magic/)
- [Rice University](http://dsp.rice.edu/cs)
- [SparseLab](http://sparselab.stanford.edu/)
- [SPGL1](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Empf/spgl1/index.html)

Hope that helps.